# Exception-Raising Win32 API Wrapper?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, wrapper

I've seen many wrappers for the Windows API (MFC, ATL, WTL, etc.) but none of them seem to use exception-handling -- you still have to check the error codes for most functions, which is easy to forget (or to omit due to laziness).

Is there any wrapper out there that actually throws exceptions instead of returning error codes?

Comment: The corollary is that you still have to catch the exceptions and do something with them; catch(...) { printf("oh noes!"); } is no better than omitting error checking.  Anyway, both MFC and ATL occasionally use exceptions; I guess it depends on who wrote what class as it is not consistent throughout the framework.  I would expect other frameworks to be similar as throwing exceptions may not be the best approach for every occasion.

Comment: @Luke: Well, you don't expect something like `ListView_GetItemRect` to be unsuccessful, so I think it's better if it crashes your code rather than just forcing you to handle it in every situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [VCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library) raises exceptions when it encounters errors.

Comment: Yup, so do Winforms, WPF and WinRT.  C++ programmers have C with classes codebases that are not exception safe.  Like Google.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Hm... I'm having a little trouble finding the download link (or the actual website, in fact)... any idea where the site itself is located?

Comment: @Hans: Huh... is that a Good Thing or a Bad Thing?

Comment: VCL is part of Delphi and C++ Builder. You don't download it.

Comment: @David: LOL, I was surprised to see a VCL answer to a Visual Studio question :-)